# Adminjs - Cannot find module '@adminjs/mongoose' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: node.js, typescript, adminjs

I couldn't import this from adminjs

```
import * as AdminJSMongoose from '@adminjs/mongoose'
import AdminJS from 'adminjs'
```

comment i used for install mongoose

```
npm i @adminjs/mongoose
```

the Error shown like this

**Cannot find module '@adminjs/mongoose' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307**

I want to import adminjs mongoose but even after installation it say couldn't find module i'm using ts with node and express